# Memory Leak in Functional Programming

Tags: memory-leaks, functional-programming

Because in pure functional programming objects are all immutable, is it still possible to create memory leak?

By pure functional program, I meant there are no side effect. Of course, this is not realistic since every program has I/O. But, let's just ignore the I/O for now.

Comment: You can cause `Stack Overflow` with recursive functions. very easy.

Comment: You can also hold onto the head of a sequence.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952602/does-haskell-require-a-garbage-collector

Comment: How do you define memory leak in this context? Also, there is no pure functional program, otherwise you would never see a result of your program.

Comment: I think by the definition, `stack overflow` is not memory leak since you don't loose any references.

Comment: @gyoho You also don't loose any references in Java. Yet one can have memory leaks by keeping around references that are no longer needed.

Comment: @Henry I see your point. So, memory leak is not a matter of FP or OOP. It's really about memory management.

Comment: Echoing previous comments, how do you define a memory leak?

Comment: @Henry "there is no pure functional program, otherwise you would never see a result of your program." not true, if printing is part of run-time system that runs your pure program. which it is, for any pure FPL. your pure FP program constructs an IO program, that is run by RTS *later*. that's the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a matter of how we define a memory leak. A program that runs for a very long time (potentially endlessly, like a server) can have a memory usage that is bounded or that grows more and more the longer the program is running. In the latter case, one speaks usually of a memory leak.

It is easy to write a functional program that needs more and more memory the longer it runs. So in that sense, memory leaks are possible.